# Named output parameters vs return values

Tags: documentation, functions, out-parameters

Which code is better:

```
// C++
void handle_message(...some input parameters..., bool& wasHandled)
void set_some_value(int newValue, int* oldValue = nullptr) 

// C#
void handle_message(...some input parameters..., out bool wasHandled)
void set_some_value(int newValue, out int oldValue)
```

or

```
bool handle_message(...some input parameters...) ///< Returns -1 if message was handled
                                                //(sorry, this documentation was broken a year ago and we're too busy to fix it)
int set_some_value(T newValue) // (well, it's obvious what this function returns, so I didn't write any documentation for it)
```

The first one doesn't have any documentation, but it doesn't need it. It's a self-documenting code. Output value clearly says what it means, and it's really hard to make a change like this:

```
- void handle_message(Message msg, bool& wasHandled) {
-    wasHandled = false;
-    if (...) { wasHandled = true; ...
+ void handle_message(Message msg, int& wasHandled) {
+    wasHandled = -1;
+    if (...) { wasHandled = ...;
```

When the code uses return values, it's easy to change them and leave the comments broken:

```
  /// Return true if message was handled
- bool handle_message(Message msg) {
+ int handle_message(Message msg) {
...
-     return true;
+     return -1;
```

Most of compilers don't (and can't) check the documentation which is written in comments. Programmers also tend to ignore comments when they edit the code.

So the question is:
if a *subroutine* has a single output value,
should it be a *procedure* with well-named self-documenting output parameter,
or should it be a *function* which returns an unnamed value with a comment describing it?

Comment: Bad documentation will always cause issues. It is not something special that out parameters fix.

Comment: @unholysampler, what do you mean by "bad documentation" - wrong documentation, or lack of documentation, or what?

Comment: Well, now that edit changes things.  :P

Comment: Not really.  The answer is still **neither**.  It should be a well-named function which returns a useful and relevant value.  `handle_message` is not a well-named function.

Comment: @Bobson Neither?  The question is "should it return the value or should it use the output parameter?"  If the answer is "neither", you'll get no result.  (Unless you store the results in some global location, which is really bad.)

Comment: @Bobson please suggest another name.

Comment: @Richard - No, the OP's question is "No return and well-named output or unnamed result with comments." As I said, it should be a *well named function* with result, which is neither of those two, although it's closer to the latter.

Comment: @Abyx - That depends on what it's supposed to do.  `bool is_valid_message(Message msg)`.  `bool try_handling_message(Message msg)`.  `int get_message_status(Message msg)`.  `MessageResult process_message(Message msg)`....  The first is clearly true if it's a valid message.  The second is (by convention) true if the message was handled successfully.  The third is clearly some type of status value (which you'd have to look up regardless if it was from a `return` or an `out`).  The last is very clear about what it is.

Comment: @Abyx: "Bad" in the general sense. Self-documenting code can only go so. There will be things you can't state with just the type system and descriptive names. Output parameters are not the only way to achieve code that has descriptive names. Most languages don't let you say an `int` argument must be between 0 and the length of a list - 1. You are going to need documentation for that. This is true in purely functional programing as well. You are not going to get an answer that says output parameters are always better than return values.

Comment: @Bobson, will you make that reply an answer, including different cases of message and event processing, e.g. `void processEvent(SomeEvent event, ref string eventResult, ref string otherEventResult, out bool stopEventPropagation)` ? Maybe with examples from existing libraries and frameworks.

Comment: @Abyx - Answered.

Comment: Side-effect free functions are hard to write if you are relying on output tagged parameters.

Comment: @JustinC, side-effect free? Do you mean the `process_message` and `set_value` functions? Well yeah, I'd even say it's impossible to make them side-effect free.

Comment: [Side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science) and [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) basically you can repeat the function call with the same inputs and expect the same output because there has been no change to the containing system/environment and the parameters.  Because most function calls are by value, you are given the opportunity to do whatever you want to the input without modifying the state of the source for those parameters.  Out is only slightly more than a special kind of call by reference, which allows changes to reflect back.

Comment: @Bobson Aah, ok.  Gotcha.  I had a feeling I wasn't understanding you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit** (since the question has changed)

If your method only has one output, of course you return that value.

```
bool DoStuff(...)
```

is much more readable when you use it than

```
void DoStuff(..., out bool success)
```

Look at the sample usage:

```
if(DoStuff(....))
```

vs

```
DoStuff(..., out success)
if (success)
```

Also, it allows in-lining and chaining (if the language supports it):

```
ProcessRequest(GetRequest(reqID))
newval = ProcessString(oldval).Replace("/t","")
```

Converting these to "out" params would lead to much uglier code, plus it's just wrong.

For 1 return, always use return values.

Comment: When I see `bool DoStuff(...)` I have no idea what that `bool` means. Is it "that stuff was good, let's do it again" or "we did enough of that stuff, let's stop" or something else - I don't know. Or maybe it has nothing to do with doing stuff? But with `void DoStuff(..., out bool success)` or `void DoStuff(..., out bool dontDoItAgain)` I know what that output value means.

Comment: @Abyx - That's a problem with the function name being `DoStuff()`, not with needing a return value.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to return a failure condition from a function, you need to name it appropriately, so that it's clear what the return value is.  DoStuff() returning a boolean would be "true" for success.  FailToDoStuff() would return "true" for failure--but that's an entirely different pattern.

Comment: Another example:  if ProcessRequest() returns a boolean, "true" should *always* mean "success".  Otherwise, it's just nonsensical.

Comment: `ProcessRequest` returning `true` isn't a great example.  Even if processing failed, it still processed as much as it could for as long as it could.  `true || false` is ambiguous.  Are you trying to derive a conclusion from the input?  `isActionable`  Or are you attempting to transform and record it?  `wasRecorded`  And so on..

Comment: @JustinC Yeah, I see what you're saying, but at that point we're getting into states and such.  If you're looking for a simple boolean return value, requests such as "Do", "Process", "Execute", "Run", "Set", etc. returning a simple boolean should be "true" for success.  If it's possible to have multiple states (Logged but not exected, logged and executed, complete failure, etc.) then a simple Boolean value isn't what you want--you want an int/enum/state.

Answer (score 9):

Make functions return values. This isn't any sort of functional thing or even relatively modern. If you're unclear about what the function is returning, then your function needs a better name. If your code is doing the wrong things, fix and/or test it.

In a vacuum, the only time that modifying your inputs is acceptable is when that input is `this` in object oriented languages or when the return value is taken by someother part of the function call (things like `TryParse`).

**edit:** *(because the question changed)*

> So, again, the question is: if subroutine has single output value, should it be a procedure with well-named self-documenting output parameter, or should it be a function which returns an unnamed value and have a comment describing it?

Neither. It should be a function that is well named so that its output is clear at the **call-site**. The comment at the declaration only helps in the declaration. Making comments at all the call-sites is inane and unmaintainable.

If you can't make a good function name to describe its output, *rethink your design.*

Comment: But functions always return values.  That's why they're functions rather than procedures/methods.  When do you choose to make it a function rather than a procedure with output variables?

Comment: @richard - Always (except for the two scenarios above). Frankly, distinguishing between functions, methods and procedures is fairly meaningless. They're all the same thing under the hood, and should follow the same design guidelines.

Comment: So, you always use functions?  What about "Try" type cases (TryResolve, TryParse, etc.) or cases with multiple outputs?

Comment: @richard - sorry about the edit. I will use them for the `Try<foo>` cases, but will work to avoid them. Multiple outputs are to be avoided, as they're a code smell for violating Single Responsibility (which I find is just as applicable in function design).

Comment: @Richard In some languages you'd return an Option type. That many don't have a construct like this supported off the bat is unfortunate, because it's the kind of behavior we're trying to emulate with `bool TryFoo(out Bar)`

Comment: Please suggest another names for `handle_message` and `set_some_value` functions, so it would be clear what they return.

Comment: "Make functions return values" - can you also explain *why* functions should return values? "the only time that modifying your inputs is acceptable" - again, why?

Comment: @Abyx - Functions have a return type for a reason.  You're introducing needless complexity by throwing that away by making everything `void` with `out` parameters.

Comment: @Abyx Easy: a function that does not return a value is a contradiction. ALL functions should return a value; otherwise they aren't functions. What you really want to ask is "why not use procedures, then?".

Comment: @AndresF. it's just terminology. E.g. C++ has no "procedures", nor "methods" - only "functions".

Comment: @Abyx In C++, `void` functions aren't functions. They are procedures by another name. C++ _does have_ procedures, like you pointed out; it just doesn't single them out by name. So your question remains: "when should we prefer functions to procedures, and why?".

Comment: @Bobson. yep, we also have the `void` type for some reason. We also have `function` and `procedure` keywords in Pascal,  `proc` in assemblers, and none of them in C++. guess why.

Comment: @AndresF., nope, that's not my question. my question is "should I use named output parameters instead of unnamed return values with comments with documentation on them"

Comment: @Abyx - And the answer we're giving you is **neither**.

Comment: @Telastyn: I disagree with your comment about multiple return values being a violation of SRP.  Usually the values are related, as in perl's localtime, i.e they aren't really multiple values they are part of a tupple or anonymous object.

Comment: @jmoreno - if they're significant enough to modify your function's signature, they're significant enough to get their own type.

Comment: @abyx - functions that do not return values necessarily have side effects (even if that side effect is on the environment), or else they're meaningless.

Comment: @Telastyn - Nice edit.  Much more succinct than mine.

Comment: In my IDE, you can see comments at declaration, if you move mouse cursor over function identifier at call site.

Comment: @abyx - which is thoroughly less efficient then just *reading what is in front of you*.

Comment: @Telastyn, well, at call site you don't see parameter names either.

Answer (score 4):

One reason to write proper functions with return values (as opposed to procedures-in-disguise with "output" variables) is composability.

If you have functions (excuse my pseudocode) `void f(in: int x, out: int y)` and  `int g(in: int x)`, how do you compose them?

You cannot apply `g` to `f` applied to... say, 42:

```
int y = g(f(42));
```

Instead, you need to write:

```
int x = 0;
f(42, x);
int y = g(x);
```

Which is definitely clumsier and more error-prone. And composability matters a lot in languages with first-class functions.

---

Here is another example, hopefully more convincing: I'd like to be able to write

```
int maxSum = max(sumOfArray(array1), sumOfArray(array2)));
```

instead of jumping through hoops to achieve the same:

```
int sum1 = 0;
sumOfArray(array1, sum1);

int sum2 = 0;
sumOfArray(array2, sum2);

int maxSum = 0;
max(sum1, sum2, maxSum);
```

Hopefully this is a less contrived scenario illustrating why function composition is useful, and why it requires that the function returns its result instead of modifying an "out" variable.

Comment: In real code, functions are not called "f" and "g". They're called "createThingsList", "processThingsList", "adjustThingSize" or "isPlanetWhichCalledEarthFlat". You don't want co compose them.

Comment: You also don't have parameters and variables called "x" and "y" unless they are coordinates. You have "blueThing", "someEventInformation", etc.

Comment: @Abyx yes they will have better names in reality but totally disagree that you don't want to compose functions IRL

Comment: @Abyx I thought it was clear `f` and `g` are placeholder names, and not actual function names. Same with variable names. You are arguing minutiae instead of the actual point. Was the downvote yours?

Comment: @Abyx In any case, I assume you are used to naming conventions from C++ or C#. In other languages, [function and variable names like `f` and `x` are encouraged in the right context](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#map).

Comment: @Abyx Haskell is used in [real-world software](http://xmonad.org/), unlike brainfuck. Are you trolling? Your post was initially language agnostic; if you only care about C++ and C#, mark it as such.

Comment: of course, if function clearly states what it returns, there is no need in named output parameter. E.g. `sumOfArray` obviously returns a sum. But I'm asking about functions which aren't named after their output values.

Comment: If you _can't_ edit the source code, then you can't do anything about preexisting functions, neither adding an output variable nor renaming the function, so the point is moot. If you _can_ edit the source code, then the right course of action is renaming the function and having it return the proper value.

Comment: @Abyx I disagree about GHC. But if you prefer, here's **Scala**'s map signature: `def
map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): TraversableOnce[B]` from `Iterable`. Notice the `f` in there? It means "any function with the right signature" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your function return something that is obviously a return value. It's also useful to send error message back to the UI when something fails.

```
ReturnValue myFunction(object newValue)

class ReturnValue
{
    public bool Success {get;set;}
    public object OldValue {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes. But it often ends with `MyFunctionReturnValueType`, because you have a lot of different functions with different return types or different meanings of their return values.

Comment: Often, a Tuple<A,B> is sufficient.

Comment: @Ingo with tuple<string, string> you have no idea what output values are, or what is their order in tuple.

Comment: @Abyx - Some documentation is unavoidable in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is

> If subroutine has single output value, should it be a procedure with well-named self-documenting output parameter, or should it be a function which returns an unnamed value and have a comment describing it?

and the answer to that is **neither** (or, perhaps, both).  If you only have a single output value, you should *definitely* be using functions, not `void` procedures.  But the function's name should make it trivial to see what the return value is, so it's not an "unnamed" value and it doesn't need a comment.

Your example is called `handle_value(Message msg)`.  This is a bad function name, unless you don't care about the results (although see the last example below).  Compare it to C#'s default for handling events: `void btnCreateTransfer_Click` - the calling function doesn't care what happens inside this function, so we don't return anything, and the name just says that it does a "click" on "btnCreateTransfer".

Depending on what you want to get back out of your `handle_value` logic, there's a number of ways you can rename it.

- If you just want to check that it is able to be handled (i.e. the message was valid), you can define it as `bool is_valid_message(Message msg)`.  The result is clearly true if it is valid, and false if not.

  - C#: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`
- If you just want to know whether it was successfully handled, you can name it `bool try_handling_message(Message msg)`, or `bool handled_message(Message msg)`, or have a coding convention that any `bool` result from an unclear function is expressly success or failure.

  - C#: `int.TryParse()` - this has an `out` parameter for the value, but the function itself tells you whether it was successful.
- If you need more details from your response, you can use `int get_message_status(Message msg)`.  Obviously, you'd need some way to know what the `int` result meant.  It could have meaning on its own or it could be defined in a constant.

  - C#: `Stream.Read()` returns the number of bytes read.
- Finally, you can return a custom type - either an `enum` or an actual `class`.  The `enum` works just like the `int`, except that it conveys meaning of its own so it gives you the most freedom of naming.  The `class` lets you encapsulate and return as much data as you need.

  - C#: `DialogResult myform.ShowDialog()` - `ShowDialog()` isn't very explicit about what it returns, but because it's a `DialogResult` value, you know exactly what it is returning.
  - `MessageResult process_message(Message msg)` - You process the message and get the result of doing so.  This can also be your original `handle_message`, but then it would be something like `HandledMessageResult handle_message(Message msg)`.

Good code is self-documenting in that the functions, classes, and variables all explain what they are and what they do.  If you can name an `out` parameter clearly enough to know what's being returned, you can work that into the name of the function.  And if you can't name your `out` well and you can't name the function well, then you can still name the *type* of the return usefully. (see `ShowDialog()`)

Comment: oh, WinForms events. Did you notice that all of them have `void` return type? Why do you ignore all the events which have output values? E.g. FormClosing, Drag&Drop events, etc?

Comment: in `handle_message(out bool wasHandled)`, false value of `wasHandled` doesn't mean "failure" or "success". It means that there is no need to pass message to next handler. Something like "stop event propagation" if we'd use term "event" instead of "message". As for Windows window messages, DOM events, etc. And yeah, `wasHandled` has nothing to do with message result and actual message processing. Handler can process message, but return `wasHandled == false` if it wants to pass the message to a next handler.